# Pasar de unsigned char a vector (array)

Tags: array, c

Mi duda es la siguiente:

Estoy programando en C y compilando con XC8 en MPLAB X. Tengo un sensor que me devuelve datos en forma de "unsigned char"(8 bits por dato) y me gustaría acceder a los bits de ese byte de dato.

Había pensando en convertir el unsigned char a un array pero es en este paso donde me quedo atrancado ya que mi nivel de programación es bastante pésimo.

¿Creéis que la mejor manera para acceder a los bits que componen un byte en concreto es convirtiéndolos en array o existe otro método para esto?.

Basicamente quiero acceder a cada bit que conforma el unsigned char para comprobar mediante leds los bits que se convierten en 1.

Muchas Gracias.

Comment: Alberto, bienvenido a SOes. Te recomiendo hacer el [tour]. Tu pregunta es bastante buena. Si pudieras [edit] tu pregunta e incluir lo que has intentando en forma de un [mcve], tu pregunta tendra aun mas relevancia y podras obtener una mejor respuesta.

Comment: Alberto probaste enmascarar los bits?, por ejemplo si te responde con 10101001 y lo enmascaras con un AND 00000001 para saber si el bit menos significativo es 1. o con un 00000010 para saber si el segundo bit menos significativo es 1.